# She waited for the guests until they "have arrived" or "had arrived?

Tags: grammar

**She waited for the guests until they "have arrived" or "had arrived"**

i feel like **She waited for the guests until they have arrived** is the correct answer

because the first action is her waiting for guests to arrive

and the second action is the arrival of guests

but my textbook says the correct answer is **"had arrived"**

correct me if i am wrong

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of the versions in the question is very idiomatic. It's not wrong in terms of *have* versus *had*, but comparing those exact two sentences is quite unusual.

Instead, I would compare these two:

> 1. ✘ She **waited** until the guests **have** arrived.
>   2. ✔ She **waited** until the guests **had** arrived.

Between those two, it's the combination of *waited* and *had* that sounds best, because both are in a similar past tense. The first is not outright wrong, but it's unnatural to the point that it would never normally be used.

You could also simply drop the helper verb altogether:

> ✔ She **waited** until the guests **arrived**.

---

On the other hand, the reverse is the case if the tense of *waited* is changed to the present:

> 3. ✔ She **waits** until the guests **have** arrived.
>   4. ✘ She **waits** until the guests **had** arrived.

Or, as before, you can drop the helper verb—but doing so would mean also tweaking the final verb:

> ✔ She **waits** until the guests **arrive**.

---

Finally, a variation can be used if *for* is really to be used instead of *until*:

> ✔ She **waited** for the guests **to arrive**.
>   ✔ She **waits** for the guests **to arrive**.

The infinitive can be used in both sentences, since it, itself, doesn't have a tense.

Comment: Bassford.What about  **She had waited until the guests arrived**.The first action is waiting and the arrival of guests is the second action.

Comment: @JVL That would work too—as would *she has waited until the guests arrived*, in the right context. But it's the tense of *waited* that's determining the tense that comes later.

Comment: @JasonBassford i have same confusion as JVL , how are we able to use past perfect with the second action in  "She waited until the guests **had arrived**."  when past perfect is used to talk about an action that happened before another action in the past , in this case first action is  is waiting and second one is arrival of guests.what do you mean by "it's the combination of waited and had that sounds best" ?

Comment: @AmirWG Generally, although certainly not always, the tenses in a sentence should remain the same. When they are different (again, depending on the specific sentence), it can sound strange, if not even illogical. For instance, you would not normally say, *I ate a meal that will be prepared next week.* In this case, *waited* is past tense and *have* is present tense; the two do not work together idiomatically. It should be either  *waited* and *had* (both past tense) or *waits* and *have* (both present tense).

Comment: @JasonBassford i get it now , thanks a lot for your time.